# How do you get a program to show up in Open with?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I would like html files to open up in Chrome by default but I would like to be able to right click > Open with > and select Visual Web Developer.

Visual Studio doesn't show up in the Open with menu. Even after I hunt down VWDExpresss.exe Windows is not smart enough to populate the Open with menu with Visual Web Developer.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you change the app to Edit with to Visual Web Designer.

Open the Windows Registry by pressing [Windows R], typing [regedit] and hitting [enter]. Locate the following Registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations

In there you find all the different file types and they association. The order is filetype > shell > edit > command. Not every filetype has that chain but the most common ones do. To edit the default text editor in Windows you need to locate the HTML subkey and follow the path mentioned above until you reach the command key. There should be only one Default entry in there:

%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD++.EXE %1

To change the program that opens when clicking on the Edit option in the right-click menu simply change the path so that it leads to the application that you want to use, e.g., Visual Web Designer.

Comment: This is what mine looks like http://imgur.com/HG37Uu0

Answer (score -1):

Download [OpenWithView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/open_with_view.html).

It will allow you to modify your *open with...* context menu. You can either add or remove programs that appear in there.

Comment: OpenWithView does not explicitly support Win7 which is what he uses. Its support ends with Vista.